# I can't connect to Mariadb db through my android studio app

Tags: android-studio, mariadb

I want to connect my android studio app with a local mariadb db but it won't connect.
I have the implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.1.2' on the graddle.
I've tried everything I could but it didn't work.

This is the code I call when I push a button:

```
try {
                Connection connection = null;
                    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://192.168.56.1:3306//rollyourlife", "root", "password");

                String consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nom_usu, contra_usu, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(consulta);
                statement.setString(1, n);
                statement.setString(2, c);
                statement.setString(3, e);
                statement.executeUpdate();
                // Operaciones de base de datos aquí

                connection.close();
                result = "Conexión exitosa";
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
                ce.printStackTrace();
                result = "Error: clase no encontrada";
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                result = "Error al conectarse a la base de datos";
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I get this error message:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=127.0.0.1)(port=3306)(type=primary). failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306) from /127.0.0.1 (port 52114) after 30000ms:

Comment: _"I want to connect my android studio app with a local mariadb db"_ Local as in running on your computer? And the app is running on either a physical device or in the emulator, I suppose. The emulator may need some settings tweaked to be able to access anything running on the same computer and a physical device is more complicated. There are services like e.g. [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that provide a public internet address for a specific port on your computer, but then you need to remember that others can access it too. (So do have a proper MariaDB password.)